# Python - Checking every item in a list against every other item efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm working on a game where each object should check if it is colliding with any other object. I have a single list of all the objects and a function which can determine if two objects are colliding and destroys them. The current method I'm using is very inefficient.

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list1:
        if collide(i, j):
            i.kill()
            j.kill()
```

Initially I removed both objects from the list after they were killed, but some collision occurred without detecting so I reverted back to this code. It works, but I'd like something more efficient.

Comment: Why not check if an item collides with anything when it moves?

Comment: Are your objects sprites in pygame? If so, there is better collision detection. Please be more specific about the data types and environment you are using.

Comment: @zacharybys All objects are always in motion. The game involves a gravity model with asteroids always under gravitational acceleration.

Comment: @RoryDaulton It is in pygame, however all sprites are circles so the built in rect collision will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first this is testing twice too much and also testing if one object collides with itself:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list1:
        if collide(i, j):
            i.kill()
            j.kill()
```

This loops exactly `len(list1)**2` times.

a very simple way to divide the number of tests by 2 (and avoiding testing against itself):

```
for i,obj1 in enumerate(list1):
   for j in range(i+1,len(list1)):
      obj2 = list1[j]
      if collide(obj1,obj2):
         obj1.kill()
         obj2.kill()
```

It takes advantage of the fact that `collide(obj1,obj2)` is the same as `collide(obj2,obj1)`.

At this point, you probably want to `break` out the inner loop since obj1 is now dead. But that depends on what you want to do.

If an accurate collision test is expensive, you could consider a rougher check (distance, rectangle boundary, any quick method), so you can discard items which are too far away from each other without performing the "expensive" test.

Comment: So this is checking first item against all items, second item against all but first item, third item against all but first two items, and so on?

Comment: yes, exactly. `collide(obj1,obj2)` is the same as `collide(obj2,obj1)`

Comment: Right, that's why it was so inefficient. Thanks for the help, I'll mark it.

Comment: it has still O(n**2) complexity, but is at least twice as fast.

Comment: Is that the fastest possible way to check every item against every item once, or can it get more efficient?

Comment: since you're performing a distance check, I don't see a better way. But your distance function can be optimized maybe (a classic mistake is to compute square root instead of computing square distance)

Comment: I have to use square root for the Pythagorean theorm converting xy components back to a vector form, but in my gravitational acceleration equation I am only squaring. 

a = k * m / d^2